# C++ Cannot convert child* to parent* by assignment

Tags: c++

Using the following two classes...

```
//pure virtual...
class Monkey
{
public:
    virtual ~Monkey(){}
    virtual void clearMonkeys() = 0;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<std::vector<sf::Text>> getMonkeyListPtr() = 0;
    virtual void addMonkey(String message,Vector2f position,float depthValue) = 0;
};

class NullMonkey : public Monkey
{
public:
    NullMonkey () {/*Do Nothing*/}
    virtual ~NullMonkey () {/*Do Nothing*/}
    virtual void clearMonkeys(){/*Do Nothing*/};
    virtual std::shared_ptr<std::vector<sf::Text>> getMonkeyListPtr()
    {
        //Do Nothing but...
        //Return NULL shared pointer
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<sf::Text>> nullSharedPointer;
        return nullSharedPointer;
        //Of course I am ASSUMING I will check for NULL pointer...
    }
    virtual void addMonkey(String message,Vector2f position,float depthValue){/*Do Nothing*/};
};
```

...I have issues when casting.
Specifically I am using these classes as static members and have a situation where if one class is not available I use the Null class to fall back on to prevent app crash. It also adds the ability to hot-swap child classes for debug purposes.

Unfortunately the following...

```
class ServLoc
{
public:

    ServLoc();

    static void initialize()
    {
        theMonkey = &theNullMonkey; //Error here
    }

    //...

    static Monkey* theMonkey;
    static NullMonkey theNullMonkey;
};
```

...throws 'cannot convert NullMonkey* to Monkey* in assignment'.

I should also add add I have defined the static members in the .cpp file

```
NullMonkey ServLoc::theNullMonkey;
Monkey* ServLoc::theMonkey;
```

The funny thing is I have used similar classes in similiar situations before and did not get this error. I am at a loss. It is probably something simple but still...

In fact I implement a log class using this method. It means I can hot-swap various forms of logging (including the null logger to disable logging) and have access to the logger wherever by just using the ServLoc static members...

```
class Logger
{
public:
    virtual ~Logger() {}
    virtual void log(const logType type,const char *message) = 0;
    //...
};

class NullLogger : public Logger
{
public:
    virtual ~NullLogger() {/*Do Nothing*/};
    NullLogger() {/*Do Nothing*/};
    virtual void log(const logType type,const char *message) {/*Do Nothing*/};
    //...
};
```

This when used in same way in ServLoc as shown above works fine!?
Any ideas?

Regards

Edit - Fixed spelling mistakes

Comment: `theNullmonkey` != `theNullMonkey` - check your spelling. Likewise for `themonkey` != `theMonkey`.

Comment: Other than those typos, [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15afb4e422bd00c2).

Comment: Oh dear. Must be typo in code that IDE is not picking up then... time to squint at the screen for a few hours.

Comment: It was time to do that _before_ posting here.

Comment: I agree and I did and even now afterwards I still haven't found the mistake. Pulling hair out now! It was worth it to see that it wasn't a conceptual problem. Next step is to rewrite the whole thing from scratch and see if I encounter same issue... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (could you clarify?), that you are calling the static function initialize() from another statically initialized class? Since this would all be done at program startup (and C++ does not guarantee any static initialization order between files), initialize may be called before `ServLoc::theNullMonkey;` has been constructed?!

Comment: It was called in main(). I moved the call to the very first line of main() and still same error.